# Is it possible to change the order of flex items when they wrap, without using a media query?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container that displays two divs side by side on a normal screen.

```
[div1]  [div2]
```

When they wrap on a smaller device this ends up as

```
[div1]
[div2]
```

What I want is for them to appear as

```
[div2]
[div1]
```

This is trivial if done with media queries, but I have a very dynamic layout which makes that unfeasible, and the whole reason I'm using flex box is to try to avoid tedious/unaintainable media queries.

Is there some magic combination of flex CSS properties that will give me the behaviour that I desire?  I've played around quite a bit with no success, but feel this must be a relatively common CSS 'want', so hopefully someone here can answer this in seconds!

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that this is rather simple.  Just use `flex-direction:row-reverse;`

https://jsfiddle.net/gveukj1j/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="div2">
      Div 2
  </div>
  <div id="div1">
      Div 1
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* the relevant CSS */

#container{display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;flex-direction:row-reverse}
#container>div{flex-basis:400px;flex-shrink:0}

/* CSS to make the demo clear */

#container>div{line-height:200px;height:200px;color:#fff;text-align:center}
#div1{background:blue}
#div2{background:red}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem and was struggling with `flex-direction` controlling the order regardless of wrapping or not. Turns out `flex-wrap` has a `wrap-reverse` option that does exactly what you want in this case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Answer (score 0):

you can look at `flex-direction` and `order`:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
div {
  flex: 1;
  /* give them a size */
  min-width: 400px;
  border: solid;
  padding: 1em;
}
.a {
  order: 1
}
.b {
  order: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
```

codepen to play with : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoeOrv